# Django - Why does Django set `request.data` to QueryDict class when a file is attached, but a dict when no file is attached?

Tags: python, django

So I have a test where I don't attach a file to the request

```
>>>request.data
{'description': 'Some Goal text', 'end_date': '2021-12-04', 'goal_category': 'health', 'body': 'Some text #blah\r#weeeee\x0c#foo', 'creator': '6badb4b8-33ba-4bb9-aa9a-2e3afb359960', 'type': <PostType.DECLARE: 'DE'>}
>>>type(request.data)
<class 'dict'>
```

`>>>` denotes where I input into the debug console and below it is what is printed out. Then I attach a file and send in the request and I get this.

```
>>>type(request.data)
<class 'django.http.request.QueryDict'>
>>>request.data
<QueryDict: {'join_goal': ['d2f5aa8d-4cd0-4051-9d1a-35b28af276d5'], 'body': ['Some text and an image'], 'images': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: test.jpg (text/plain)>], 'creator': ['6badb4b8-33ba-4bb9-aa9a-2e3afb359960'], 'type': [<PostType.UPDATE: 'UP'>]}>
```

Why does Django use a QueryDict when an image comes in?

**Requested added code**

```
def set_request_data_for_post(request):
    request.data['creator'] = str(request.user.uuid)
    body_text = request.data['body']
    hash_tags = create_hashtags_uuid_list(body_text)

    if len(hash_tags) > 0:
        request.data.setlist('hash_tags', hash_tags)

    tagged_users_list = extract_usernames(body_text)

    tagged_users = list()
    for username in tagged_users_list:
        try:
            tagged_users.append(str(User.objects.get(username=username).uuid))
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            pass

    if len(tagged_users) > 0:
        request.data.setlist('tagged_users', tagged_users)

    return request
```

This new `request` var gets passed to a serializer.

Comment: Is it Django Rest Framework?

Answer (score 3):

When DRF receives a request it select the appropriate parser from the ones defined on the view or from the [defaults](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/#default_parser_classes)

The default parsers include the [JSONParser](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#jsonparser) which is used when JSON data is received and returns a `dict` and the [MultiPartParser](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#multipartparser) which is used when multipart data (the content type used when uploading files) is received and returns a `QueryDict`

Comment: so does that mean you can force it to use dict for every request rather than QueryDict? Is there a reason it switches it? It seems kind of annoying to deal with, because sometimes I modify the request data, because I generate some of the data that'll be serialized on my end and not having a consistent class type coming in causes issues. For example to set a dict you just do `dict[key]=value`, but with QueryDict you need to do `querydict.setvalue(key, value)`. Setting a QueryDict like a dict causes issues.

Comment: Why would you modify `request.data`? You can always turn a QueryDict into a dict `querydict.dict()`

Comment: Well for me specifically I need a creator for everything that comes in. I get an auth token that when decoded has the user's UUID. So I set `request.data['creator']` using that. Or another example I have is that I have data come in and I want to parse it of hash tags, then set that attribute in the `request.data` so the serializer can handle turning it into an object. Perhaps this isn't the best way to do things, it's causing me a lot of issues.

Comment: Can you add an example view/serializer?  There are other ways of passing extra data to your serializers, context for example https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context

Comment: I've added to the original post. If this is bad Django practice and there are better ways to do this I would absolutely like to know.

Comment: I looked into using `context` it seems like this data doesn't get treated as a field in the serializer, which is what I would like.